# I am getting this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group', when translating a column with multiple language into english

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate

I am using the below approach to convert a column 'comments' in my dataframe which has textual data in multiple languages including english. I want to convert the whole column in English.

Sample Data:

| listing_ID | comments |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Great location Clean spacious flat Would recommend to anyone |
| 02 | Mi mejor recomendación para este departamento Cuida todos los detalles adicionalmente muy cómodo limpio funcional y situado perfectamente |
| 03 | Muy buen host siemore atento y amable |
| 04 | excelente todo la amabilidad de Lorenzo la ubicación la habitación súper recomendarle seguro que volveremos |
| 04 | Great location and enough space in the apartment for people Although the mattresses were a bit too soft and the house is quite noisy its a solid choice for a big group of people for a weekend in barcelona |

i used this line of code to translate the data:

```
# Import the library:

import googletrans

from googletrans import Translator

# Create a translator object:

translator = Translator() 

# Use translate method to translate the column. 

df_review['trans_reviews'] = df_review['comments'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest = 'en').text)
```

But the output is giving this error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-85-1e3ea17d7fdc> in <module>
>       5 # Use translate method to translate the column. By default, the destination language is english:
>       6 
> ----> 7 df_review['trans_reviews'] = df_review['comments'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest =
> 'en').text)
> 
> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py
> in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    4198            
> else:    4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
> -> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    4201     4202         if len(mapped) and
> isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
> 
> pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
> 
> <ipython-input-85-1e3ea17d7fdc> in <lambda>(x)
>       5 # Use translate method to translate the column. By default, the destination language is english:
>       6 
> ----> 7 df_review['trans_reviews'] = df_review['comments'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest =
> 'en').text)
> 
> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googletrans/client.py
> in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
>     180 
>     181         origin = text
> --> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
>     183 
>     184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.
> 
> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googletrans/client.py
> in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
>      76 
>      77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
> ---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
>      79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
>      80                                     token=token, override=override)
> 
> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py
> in do(self, text)
>     192 
>     193     def do(self, text):
> --> 194         self._update()
>     195         tk = self.acquire(text)
>     196         return tk
> 
> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py
> in _update(self)
>      60 
>      61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
> ---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
>      63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
>      64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
> 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280

Comment: Hi Emma, thanks for sharing the post. I used that approach of downloading googlestrans version 3.0, Now am not getting any error in my code, but the output comes without any translation. No change in the languages.

Comment: Did you get `googletrans==3.1.0a0`?

Comment: Yes i did install googletrans==3.1.0a0 , i tried to run the code on a single word translation also, but it didn't translate. the output comes without translation.

Comment: Oh, am so sorry, it worked :)  I rebooted the IDE and tried it again and it worked. But when i applied to the whole column of my dataframe using my same code as above. I got this error : "IndexError: list index out of range " - what does this mean ?

Comment: The error message means that the code is trying to access a list where the index does not exist.  ex:)  `mylist = ['one']` then `print(mylist[1])` will raise the same error because list only has a value at `0` index.  If stacktrace points to your code, check the line to see similar thing is happening.  Otherwise, please post the new stacktrace.